# How to adapt tag video for mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

I use `video` tag at web page. It loads video file and shows that.

But it does not work on the mobile devices. How to adapt this?

Comment: Wich mobile device?

Comment: Any which resolution less than 400px

Comment: Seems I should use meia queries

Comment: It doesnt work because of the codec of the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge only MP4 is the compatible video format supported by all modern browsers and mobile OS's when used with the HTML 5 Video tag.

Not sure the video format is you are using, but MP4 should work. Otherwise, submit some code.